# Present viewcontroller on top of another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, dismiss

Here's my issue. In an iPhone app I have a viewcontroller (let's call it VC1) which has a button that when pressed displays another viewcontroller (let's call it VC2). VC2 has a button that when pressed dismisses VC2 and shows the already previously loaded VC1. However when VC2 is dismissed, the viewDidLoad method for VC1 gets called and this messes up the functionality of the app. Is there any way I can display VC2 such that when it is dismissed the viewDidLoad method for VC1 does NOT get called?

Here is the code I used...

To present VC2:

```
infoViewController* info=[[infoViewController alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:info animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To dismiss VC2:

```
-(void)dismisser{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

(dismisser is the method that gets called when dismiss button is pressed)

Comment: How are you returning to Vc1 from VC2?  Please show the code?

Comment: One moment, will edit post

Comment: can you check using flag whether viewDidLoad is called from directly when app started or it is called when VC2 dismissed ?

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that is dismissing VC2?  That code won't result in a call to `viewDidLoad`.  It will call `viewDid/WillAppear`

Comment: Do you call `ViewDidLoad` from any other places like `ViewDid/WillAppear` ?

Comment: My apologies it turns out that viewDidLoad is not actually getting called but it is some other issue causing it to refresh. I will need to look into it. Thanks everyone.